# record not found on contain model in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I am using CakePHP 3.4

I am retrieving information of user like

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'UserAddresses.States.Countries' => ['conditions' => [
               'UserAddresses.deleted' => false]],
    ],
]);
```

Here, `UserAddresses` have `user_id` column and `state_id` column and `States` table have `country_id` column.

If there is no associated user_address in table, then I gives 
`record not found` error
while removing `States.Countries` from `contain` works fine even when record does not exists in `UserAddresses`

> Edit 2 : Relationships

**UsersTable.php**

```
$this->hasOne('UserAddresses', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
]);
```

**UserAddressesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('States', [
    'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**StatesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Countries', [
    'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->hasMany('UserAddresses', [
    'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
]);
```

**CountriesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('States', [
    'foreignKey' => 'country_id'
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kilian Schuster said, your condition is being applied to `Countries`. I changed it, try the code bellow:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'UserAddresses' => [
            'conditions' => [
               'UserAddresses.deleted' => false
            ]
        ],
        'UserAddresses.States.Countries'
    ]
]);
```

> Edit: The `record not found` error could be caused by the `Inner join` type for Countries in States model if there is no address related to the got user. Change the join type to `Left` if the relationship is optional.

Comment: Update your question and tell which are the relationships between the models, depending on it, you should use matching() or innerJoinWith().

Comment: I think there is a State that has no country related, and because the Inner join type you are getting the record not found error.

Comment: There is only one state record and one country record in the table and state record is associated with country. Yes, there is not associated user_address in the table whose record I'm searching for. But It works even when there is no associated `user_address` record when removed `States.Countries` but throwing error when `States.Country` is present

Comment: Change the join type to left just to see if it works.

Comment: whose join type ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142107/discussion-between-rayann-nayran-and-anuj-tbe).

Answer (score 0):

With this syntax, you are actually trying to apply the conditions to the "Countries" model, and not to the "UserAddresses" model.